# WPF Material Design Raised Button Hovered state

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design, togglebutton

I'm trying to recreate a material design look & feel for a button. For the focused (hovered) state the guidelines say to make a 12 % #000000 shade over the button. I was wondering how this could be achieved in WPF.

I've been looking around a good option would be to add a non-hittable rectangle over the button with a 12 % opacity and a color of #000000. I want to implement this as a style, but I have no idea  how to do that.

My style looks like this at moment:

```
<Style x:Key="MaterialRaisedButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 6 8 6"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="36"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="64"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MaterialSecondaryColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource z-depth2}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid>
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="#000000" Opacity="0.12"/>
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Material12Black}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

If there are any other methods of doing this, I'm all ear as well :)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) might not answer you question but might help.

Comment: @FilipCordas Thanks, I already knew of that library but unfortunately I cannot add control libraries due to corporate decisions so I have to make lightweight copies ;)

Comment: The best way to make a 12% shaded color, is to define a `SolidBrush` with the `Color` set to `Black`, and the `Opacity` set to `0.12`.  If you use that as the background of your button (with other styles) it should just work automatically to give you what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the fill of the rectangle you can specify opacity in the hex color like #00000000, the first two values are the opacity. So 12% would be #1e000000. The following will show .5 opacity rectangle when mouse is over other wise opacity is 0.

```
 <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                        <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>

    </Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

If anybody wants to reuse the code for a material-like button, the code is below. I used the ripple effect from [this stackoverflower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857608/androids-ripple-effect-in-wpf) along with the shadows from [this source](http://marcangers.com/material-design-shadows-in-wpf/). Hopefully this can help others recreating Material design without the toolkit :)

```
<Style x:Key="MaterialRaisedButton2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 6 8 6"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="36"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="64"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NormalTextBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MaterialSecondaryColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource z-depth2}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <cons:RippleEffectDecorator Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HighlightBackground="#1e000000" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Fill="#1e000000" Panel.ZIndex="1">
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0.12"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                                                <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </cons:RippleEffectDecorator>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1FFFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#42FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```